# Take back vote in comments

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, voting, comments

Although this is a rare case, I can't take back my vote from comments, like I can do from answers or questions. Is it only my problem, or everyone's? If everyone's, then this is a 'feature request'.

Comment: Oops, to be honest it was my question and my problem as well, so God bless you for asking such a significant question which could be so constructive for many users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the same rule about removing a vote *does* apply to questions and answers as well. From the [priveleges pages](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> You can undo your vote by clicking the same button you used to vote, so click the up arrow to undo an upvote or the down arrow to undo a downvote. To change a vote from up to down, click the down arrow, and vice versa. **Votes can only be changed for a short period of time, so be careful with those clicks!**

The exception to this rule is if the question is *edited* between the time when your vote was cast and the time you choose to remove your vote.  If that has happened, then you *are* able to remove your vote.  Since comments cannot be edited after a period of time, it makes sense that you can never change your vote.

Comment: Oops, your answer could be considered as a complete brief answer. So, to be honest, I wasn't aware about that. particularly you mentioned "You can undo your vote by clicking the same button you used to vote, so click the up arrow to undo an upvote or the down arrow to undo a downvote. To change a vote from up to down, click the down arrow, and vice versa. Votes can only be changed for a short period of time, so be careful with those clicks! ..."

Answer (score 3):

It's not just you: Comments may be upvoted, but they cannot be un-upvoted (except during a brief period after the vote itself, ostensibly to allow one to take back a mis-click).  The inability to un-upvote a comment is entirely by design (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/132874)

Comment: Why then do we have an option for answers and questions of taking back. Even they can be made to seem ostensible. Why special for comments.

Comment: @servantofWiser Honestly, I have no clue.  The fact that it *is* by-design is rather clear, but as to why...? The SE devs do as the SE devs will.

Comment: It's an overhead to program that... You see the question asked was in 2009 and got a reply in 2012. They took it that long to do it. So, flip flopping is another over head. And they did not bother cuz it's not very often do we think about taking back from comment.